# When do I use removeFromSuperview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a small question when programming objects in objective-C.  I have an App that is just about complete and everything works fine. My question is that I set my objects to nil and release them at appropriate times.

But is this enough or when and where should I use removefromsuperview?

In the case of adding a UIButton to a UITableViewCell I add the UIButton with the following code:

```
UIButton *buttonReset = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
buttonReset.frame = CGRectMake(250.0f, 7.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
[cell addSubview:buttonReset];
buttonReset addTarget:self action:@selector(resetSettings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
buttonReset = nil;
[buttonReset release];
```

Do I also need to use

```
[buttonReset removeFromSuperview];
```

in this case?

Comment: No, just make the object nil and release. That would be fine.

Comment: @Suresh That's wrong. See dasblinkenlight's and my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
buttonReset = nil;
[buttonReset release];
```

This doesn't make sense. You set a pointer to `nil` (null pointer) and then send a message to it. In most other languages this would result in a crash. In Objective-C it's allowed, but nothing will happen. You have to `release` before setting to `nil`. But you shouldn't do neither in this case, because `buttonReset` is an autoreleased object (you didn't use alloc/init to create it), so you don't own it and therefore you must not release it.

You also don't have to use `removeFromSuperview` in this case. You add a button (a subview) to your cell (the superview). The superview will hold a strong (retaining) reference of the button. When the cell is then released, it will also handle all of its subviews. You only have to remove it yourself when you actually want to do that, but not for memory management reasons.

If you didn't already know about it, you might want to consider using [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) in the future.

Comment: The `release` is not just unnecessary, it would likely result in a crash later on, when `cell` is deallocated (and releases its subviews). It won't happen if the pointer is set to `nil` before, but as you've pointed out, that doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not call `[buttonReset removeFromSuperview];`, at least not right away: if you do, the button would disappear from screen (given the name of the method, this should come as no surprise). Moreover, you do not need to set your button to `nil`.

Calling `removeFromSuperview` is needed when you need the control to be dropped from the screen. If you also release it, the object representing your control would be destroyed. For example, if you added a button programmatically for a specific task, and have to remove that button once the task has been accomplished, calling `removeFromSuperview` is appropriate.

Comment: So given that this is in a UITableCell, when I click on a cell and the UITableView is dealloc, what would be the correct order of operations that I would use? `resetButton = nil; [resetButton release];` ~OR~ `[resetButton removeFromSuperview]; resetButton = nil;` ~OR~ `[resetButton removeFromSuperview]; resetButton = nil;` ~OR~ `[resetButton removeFromSuperview]; resetButton = nil; [resetButton release];`

Comment: @ScottCleland Since your `UITableView` gets deallocated (along with all the cells it might hold) `[resetButton release];` is all you really need. Since the variable is local, it is not necessary to set it to `nil`.

Comment: So no need for `removeFromSuperview` at all?

Comment: @ScottCleland That's correct, no need to call `removeFromSuperview`. Moreover, you shouldn't even call the `release`, because the button is autoreleased (thanks DrummerB for pointing it out).

Comment: @DrummerB You're right, it's autoreleased! I didn't pay attention to the call used to create the button instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `removeFromSuperview` on a view causes it to be removed from its superview. This will make the targetted view disappear from the screen with all the view it contains.

In your situation, I would just set the object to nil and be done with it.

See [does removefromsuperview releases the objects of scrollview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340754/does-removefromsuperview-releases-the-objects-of-scrollview).

There are interesting informations in it.

> but it's worth digging deeper into this, because it's a very important
>   concept in ObjC. You should never call -release on an object you
>   didn't -retain explicitly or implicitly (by calling one of the Three
>   Magic Words). You don't call -release in order to deallocate an
>   object. You call it to release the hold you have put on the object.
>   Whether scrollview is retaining its subviews is not your business (it
>   does retain its subviews, but its still not your business). Whether
>   -removeFromSuperview calls -release is also not your business. That's betweeen the scrollview and its subviews. All that matters is that you
>   retain objects when you care about them and release them when you stop
>   caring about them, and let the rest of the system take care of
>   retaining and releasing what it cares about.

Answer (score -2):

you should use just the

```
[buttonReset removeFromSuperview];
```

and then

```
buttonReset = nil;
```

as apple saying

> If the receiver’s superview is not nil, the superview releases the receiver. If you plan to reuse a view, be sure to retain it before calling this method and release it again later as appropriate.

in [UIView Referance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Comment: @ScottCleland The table view is not deallocated (nor released) when tapping a cell. A new view controller is (probably) pushed onto the navigation controller stack, but the view controller with your table view is still kept in memory.

Comment: @ScottCleland Don't do any of those suggestions of yours. Just remove the last two lines of code in your question and you should be fine.